# Archive.php filtered by pre-determined category

Tags: categories, templates, archives

My archive.php template is formatted perfectly to list out posts from a certain month and year. However, I only want this template to show from a specific category. I can query for the specific category but then the month/year filter no longer works. How can I display posts on the archive.php template from one category?

Answer (score 1):

```
add_action( 'parse_query', 'wpse_60354_archive_category' );
function wpse_60354_archive_category( $wp_query )
{
    if ( $wp_query->is_archive() )
        $wp_query->set( 'cat', ID_OF_CATEGORY );
}
```

Just replace `ID_OF_CATEGORY` with the ID of your category, obviously ;)

Comment: I was working with this and can't seem to get it to work. Where exactly would this code be dropped in?

Comment: `functions.php` - it's not tested, so if you still get problems, let us know what's going on & we can tweak it!

Comment: Cool. I did try it out and it had no impact on the page. Would this go before or after the loop? I tried both.

Comment: The code I posted needs to go in `functions.php` - it has to run before the template is loaded!

Comment: Ahh, I put that in my functions.php template and removed it from archive.php. I replaced the ID of category which is '3' but it is not sorting my archives page by that category.

Comment: Remove `if ( $wp_query->is_archive() )` and try again - this won't be the final solution but it'll rule out a problem.

Comment: Ok, I removed that line from functions.php and nothing has changed at all.